# What is the technical difference between ? & ! in swift language?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

Can anyone explain in detail about the technical difference between ! & ? literals that we are using in swift language.  Basically in apple developer document they mentioned it as the nil validation but i didn't understand clearly about the logic behind it.  Can you one explain with some real time logic for the same.

Thanks in advance for the user.

Answer (score 9):

> Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping
>
> You specify optional chaining by placing a question mark (?) after the
>   optional value on which you wish to call a property, method or
>   subscript if the optional is non-nil. This is very similar to placing
>   an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the
>   unwrapping of its value. **The main difference is that optional chaining
>   fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping
>   triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.**

— [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_312) (emphasis added)

Nobody's going to be able to explain it more simply than that. What don't you understand?